# Programming an Attiny85

Tags: avr, avrdude, avr-studio4, attiny

I was wondering how to upload a program I wrote using AVR Studio 4 to an ATtiny85. I was basically using this tutorial http://blog.smileymicros.com/smileys-workshop-10-moving-beyond-arduino/ except doing everything with an attiny85 instead of an atmega328. I got the pins_arduino.h from HighLow tech's ATtiny library.

I have compiled successfully in AVR Studio 4 and am now wondering how to upload to an Attiny85.

Thanks

Comment: The page you refer to has the instructions for connecting to an Arduino board with avrdude. (I am assuming you are using an Arduino board?) The command line options will be slightly different, e.g. the `-p` option for the processor. Look up avrdude in Google to learn about the options.

Comment: I recommend using [arduino-tiny](https://code.google.com/p/arduino-tiny/) over ATtiny since it is more feature-complete.

Comment: What AVR programmer do you use?

Comment: I use the avr mkll or the isp programmer

Answer (score 0):

Download the Windows-Avrdude version: http://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/69851/avrdude-5.10.zip
Extract the avrdude.exe files (avrdude.conf and avrdude.exe anywhere in your directories.
Now in AVR Studio, create a new tool under external tools (don't know exactly if it is called external tools) and call it 'ATtiny85'.
Paste this line in the command field: C:\Path\To\Your\avrdude.exe.
Paste this in 'Arguments': -F -v -pt85 -cstk500v1 -P com7 -b19200 -Uflash:w:"$(ProjectDir)Debug\$(ItemFileName).hex":i -C
Make sure you replace 'com7' with your com port you've attached your avrisp mkii to.
Now finish the dialog and your ready to upload. (Just click your tool in the Menu)